# Connect a div to javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have stored objects with name and price in javascript.
I've appended them in html with individual div for every object.
When I click the div, the background color changes, to denote that you have selected the object.
But how can I bind the onscreen divs to the javascript objects?
When the user clicks the div, I want that object's 'select' property to turn to 'true'.

Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/wEF7b/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the objects in an array.

When you create the div, give it an `id` of `something_something_array_index`.

You can extract the id from it with a regular expression, `split`, etc.

---

Alternatively, you can assign arbitrary properties to HTML Element objects, so you could just do:

```
myDiv.source_data = myObject;
```

Some people argue that this is convenient, some that adding non-standard properties risks future name space collisions.

Comment: jquery provides a `$.data(key, value)` method that can also be used for this purpose.  Under the hood it's probably doing something equivalent to the above.

Comment: @SeanBright thanks, data looks useful, but is there any way to change the object directly?

Answer (score -1):

You can change an attribute you create. For example, each div can have a "selected" attribute.
You can set this attribute using jQuery:

Setter:

```
$(element).attr('selected', value)
```

Getter:

```
if($(element).attr('selected') == value
```

You can use this on your click event handler

Comment: — The basic JS object containing the data used to populate the div with content, not the HTML Div Element object.

Comment: `selected` isn't a valid attribute of a `div`.